# Подскажите паттерн для замены участка кода

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет. Есть метод, в котором производятся различные проверки. И, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы производилась проверка, и если она выдала какую-то ошибку, то метод прерывался и возвращал результат этой проверки. Я реализовал это через `if`, но у меня есть четкое ощущение, что есть какой-то паттерн для этого, а я его просто не знаю

```
checkGraphicsAndGetErrorMessage = (boundariesOptions?: BoundariesOptions): ErrorI18KeyAndOptions | undefined => {
  if (mapStore.selectedGraphic) {
    const res = this.checkGraphic(mapStore.selectedGraphic)
    if (res) {
      return res
    }
  } else {
    const res = this.checkGraphicsCollection(mapStore._graphicsLayer.graphics)
    if (res) {
      return res
    }
  }

  if (boundariesOptions) {
    return this.checkBoundaries(boundariesOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну почему вы так любите код картинками прикладывать?.. Его нельзя скопировать, читать неудобно. А переписывать с картинки его никто не будет.

Comment: код нужно прикладывать кодом, а не картинкой

Comment: @rusgeli надо наверное на мете сделать вопрос и отсылать всех тех, кто картинки вставляет туда, чтобы оставили ответы. Потому что это какая-то тотальная жесть с ними последний год точно. Интересно понять почему люди так делают

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119

Comment: @insolor  не, этот вопрос говорит о том, "почему так не надо делать" и "как надо", а я говорю о том, чтобы эти самые люди писали ответы почему они так делают. Это немного другое. Да и тему не загрязнять

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12162/508294

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> И, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы производилась проверка, **и если она выдала какую-то ошибку, то метод прерывался** и возвращал результат этой проверки.

**`const`** `res =`  **`this.`**`checkGraphic`

esma js 2015 полагаю?

---

пожалуй да, есть для таких случаев кое что давно известное и вроде удобное

```
if(x==false){trow('x false');}
/*...*/
try{...}
catch(e){...}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

сленг конечно местами мерзкий в статьях об этом - эдакий рекурсивный канцелярит, но вроде оно того стоит, чтоб разобраться.

> Конструктор Error создаёт объект ошибки. Экземпляры объекта Error выбрасываются при возникновении ошибок во время выполнения. Объект Error также может использоваться в качестве базового для пользовательских исключений. Смотрите ниже стандартные встроенные типы ошибок.

чтоб вы понимали, это **вступительный** абзац к `error()` ...)

Comment: Хах, спасибо) Думаю, потерплю обилие "объект Error" ради такого)

Comment: Нафига использовать исключения там, где их не должно быть?

Comment: @Qwertiy серьёзно? не должно быть?) ты вообще хоть частично читал топик? цитирую `и если она выдала какую-то ошибку, то метод прерывался и возвращал результат этой проверки` вообще-то если верить MDN, это ровно то для чего они и предназначены. В - внимательность))) в конце концов, то на чьем ответе поставили галочку, говорит лучше всяких слов.

Comment: @puffleeck, названия функций прочитай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну да, это самодельный обработчик ошибок судя по всему, только.... `Я реализовал это через if, но у меня есть четкое ощущение, что есть какой-то паттерн для этого, а я его просто не знаю` автор явно хотел либо заменить его целиком, либо хотя бы просто увидеть аналог, что я и показал. неужели это всё настолько не очевидно, что требуется объяснять? эм... отдохни-ка от строгой типизации, желательно склепав что-то на динамике. никаких "зачем" и "почему", просто сделай и всё.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
         mapStore.selectedGraphic
         ? this.checkGraphic(mapStore.selectedGraphic)
         : this.checkGraphicsCollection(mapStore._graphicsLayer.graphics)
       )
       || boundariesOptions && this.checkBoundaries(boundariesOptions)
       || undefined // скорее всего, можно убрать
```

Comment: тогда уж все надо было логическими делать `(mapStore.selectedGraphic && (this.checkGraphic(mapStore.selectedGraphic) || this.checkGraphicsCollection(mapStore._graphicsLayer.graphics))) || boundariesOptions && this.checkBoundaries(boundariesOptions)`

Comment: @Grundy, во-первых, ты со скобками накосячил, во-вторых, даже если исправить, то твой код будет работать не так, как у автора.

Comment: скобки вроде поправил, теперь не отличается от твоего :) твой тоже не работает так как у автора :)

Comment: @Grundy, у тебя `||` внутри аргумента функции, так что не поправил. Мой работает как у автора если считать, что единственным ложным возвращаемым значением является undefined. Твой отличается и от авторского, и от моего тем, что вызывает не те проверки.

Comment: Поправил поправил :) А, все, понял в чем подвох :)

Comment: @Grundy, да, теперь поправил. Но работает-то всё равно неверно.

Comment: @Grundy, а я добавил undifined, чтобы стало как в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо, оно работает так, как надо. Единственное, не очень читабельно получается. Просто, думал, что есть волшебный паттерн, который делает все аккуратным)